Autodesk Vault Developer Framework initial login error VDF.Vault.Library.ConnectionManager.LogIn returns false
We are trying to connect to the Autodesk Vault program through the Autodesk Vault Developer Framework and we are not able to achieve a successful login result with Python through the Pythonnet package and clr module. The following code returns a "false" result for the Autodesk.DataManagement.Client.Framework.Vault.Library.ConnectionManager.LogIn.Success method.
from pythonnet import load
load("netfx")
import clr


print("check001")
clr.AddReference("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Autodesk Vault 2024 SDK\\bin\\x64\\Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServices.dll")
import Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServices as ACW
from Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServices import *

print("check002")
clr.AddReference("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Autodesk Vault 2024 SDK\\bin\\x64\\Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServices.WCF.dll")
import Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServices.WCF as ACWW
from Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServices.WCF import *

print("check003")
clr.AddReference("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Autodesk Vault 2024 SDK\\bin\\x64\\Autodesk.DataManagement.Client.Framework.dll")
import Autodesk.DataManagement.Client.Framework as VDF
from Autodesk.DataManagement.Client.Framework import *

print("check004")
clr.AddReference("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Autodesk Vault 2024 SDK\\bin\\x64\\Autodesk.DataManagement.Client.Framework.Vault.dll")
import Autodesk.DataManagement.Client.Framework.Vault as VDFV
from Autodesk.DataManagement.Client.Framework.Vault import *



print("check005")
results: VDF.Vault.Results.LogInResult
results = VDF.Vault.Library.ConnectionManager.LogIn("tmc-vault.ad.thielenhaus.us", "TMC_Vault", "python", "Zap-Thesis-Sacrament2", VDF.Vault.Currency.Connections.AuthenticationFlags.Standard, None)

print("check006")
connection: VDF.Vault.Currency.Connections.Connection
connection = results.Connection

print("check007")
print(results.Success)

However, this connection returns "true" and works fine when programed and ran in Visual Basic.
Has anyone had this work successfully in Python? Are there any suggestions why it returns "true" with Visual Basic and "false" with Python?
We have tried changing imports and type casting variables in Python (which is typically not necessary). However, the results are the same.

It is unfortunate to inform you that Python language is not yet supported by Autodesk.
As you are trying to use Vault SDK in Python through .NET interop packages, engineering team didn't have a scenario like this and tested this scenario. So, engineering team says that there is not officially support to implement this scenario.
At the end, Autodesk do not support implementing Python using .NET interop library. Due to fact that we do not testing on this scenario.
You could create a .NET library that uses the Vault SDK which in turn would expose certain functionality to be consumed from Python - maybe that could work.
